# how to get ansi character value form database where select char

Tags: sql, database

Where I need to select char(253) and get ANSI character in Arabic collation doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct code page? ANSI is an extension of ASCII which contains characters from 0 - 127. ANSI codepages specify a range from 128-255 (top bitset characters) which can vary depending on the ANSI code page.

If you can - use UTF-8 - it'll make it easier for you in the long run.

[Further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) on wikipedia.